# Wordpress page only shows when user is logged in (even with visibility set to public)

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to troubleshoot an issue on a client's site. There is one specific page which appears as "not found" unless you log in and then visit the front end, in which case it appears normally. The visibility on the page is set to public, and in every other way it's a normal boring wordpress page. Stranger still, it only started happening recently (after months of trouble-free use).

Problem page: http://www.leecamp.net/schedule/

Any ideas why this would happen?

Comment: is it set to published? and the published date set to a date in the past and not the future?

Comment: Id also look at your 404.php page, and get it fixed, just copy page.php and rename it to 404.php, just so its more of a fit to your site and not broke. also just double check to make sure the permalink to your page matches what you have in your Title field!

Comment: @Marty... it turns out the page was "scheduled" exactly one year ago. For some reason, when the year rolled over it went back into "scheduled" status. So that solved it (except now the rest of the menu is screwed up and I'm not sure why). Can you submit your comment as an answer so I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it set to published? and the published date set to a date in the past and not the future?
Id also look at your 404.php page, and get it fixed, just copy page.php and rename it to 404.php, just so its more of a fit to your site and not broke. also just double check to make sure the permalink to your page matches what you have in your Title field!
:)

Comment: Does it matter if the title of the page doesn't match the permalink? I sometimes change the permalinks to something shorter/easier when my pages/posts title is long. Is that bad?

Comment: no, not at all, just wondering if the page was linked in correctly :)